# I receive an empty object when I module export the pool from PostgreSQL, but it works when I module export the query function itself?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have two files. I use Node.js with PostgreSQL. In the first scenario in the `index.js` I receive an empty object (so `db = {}`), however, in the second scenario I receive the wanted `query` function.

And, of course, `db.query()` doesn't work in the first scenario, but it works charmly in the second one.

If I rename the `db` to `pool` in the index.js, it still doesn't work, I get the same problem that the required variable is `{}` and does not have any query function.

Why does this happen and what happens in under hood?

**First scenario:**

db.js:

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool;

const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'postgres',
  password: 'password',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  database: 'perntodo',
});

module.export = pool;
```

**Second scenario:**

db.js:

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool;

const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'postgres',
  password: 'password',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  database: 'perntodo',
});

module.exports = {
  query: (text, params) => pool.query(text, params),
};
```

**The index.js in both scenario:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const db = require('./db');

console.log('db:', db);

// middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

// create a todo
app.post('/todos', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { description } = req.body;

    const newTodo = await db.query(
      'INSERT INTO todo (description) VALUES($1)',
      [description],
      (err, res) => {
        if (err) return next(err);
      }
    );

    res.json(newTodo);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log('Server has started on port 5000.');
});
```

Output:

**First scenario:**

```
db {}
```

**Second scenario:**

```
db { query: [Function: query] }
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a very silly mistake, I will leave the post here so maybe it will help others in the future as well.

I wrote `module.export` instead of `module.exports`.